# Error when Installing matplotlib using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pip

I know that there have already been questions pertaining to this and most of them were resolved by installing `libfreetype6-dev` and `libpng-dev`. I have installed both of those libraries using apt-get, but I am still coming up with an error when trying to use

```
pip install matplotlib
```

The error I get is:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your run into more problems you might want to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
It is a one stop shop for many python libs managing dependencies and including mathplotlib.

Comment: I had Anaconda installed, but reinstalling it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to install g++

```
sudo apt-get install g++
aptitude install g++
```